# Navigation background color is not fully displayed

Tags: css, background-color

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOaBC.png)

When the navigation is set to 100%, give him a background color, normal condition can be normal display, why after enlargement, the right navigation no background color.

Comment: no we need your `html `and `css` to help, this can be something simple but cant help without seeing the code.

Comment: What they said. But in these cases, it's usually a matter of overflow: the container has a specific width, and the contents are wider.